# I can't open or close any tabs on my Android tablet in Chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android

This is a tablet I've had for years, and suddenly it decided that tabs in Chromes cannot be selected, exited, or added (The only change I can do is the new tab button option on the 3 dots, but I can't switch back from it, or I close out of Chrome and reopen it, then I can do only one of those things, but not more).

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue too on my Galaxy Tab A.
I found a workaround. It's not the fix just a workaround. Please enable rotation of display btw. landscape and portrait. Each time you encounter this issue so you cannot close any Chrome Tabs any longer just rotate your display. That's it!

Regards and stay healthy!
Markus

Comment: I have the exact same issue in Chrome on pixel c. It happens every time i have had a video in film screen. And starter sekund the same time as you. I found the same work around, nyt it is anoying.

Comment: Same issue is in chrome 87.0.4280.141 and Android 8.1.0 on pixel c.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Samsung Note 4?? Follow this..

### 4 Ways to Fix Can’t Close Tabs in Samsung Note 4

1. Firstly, go to Settings in your Samsung Note 4 and head over to Developer Options. Then click on Input and uncheck show touches. After doing this, try again and this time you will be able to close tabs on Note-4.
   Note: If you don’t have developer options, you can get them by going to the Settings page and heading over to About Phone​ and then tapping  Build Number 7 times.
2. If you are using Chrome, head over to Chrome settings and then turn off combine tabs. This step will restart Google Chrome and you will be able to tap on the number box and close the tabs.
3. Another great fix to solve the can’t close tabs in Note 4 problem is to Go to Settings -> developer options and unchecking ‘allow mock locations’. This will fix the issue and you will be able to close all the opened tabs.
4. Go to Developer options and go to the Apps section. Here, you will see an option “ Do Not Keep Activities”  Uncheck this box and you will be able to close tabs in Samsung Note-4. If that doesn’t work, you can also check this box and then try again.

[Source](https://innov8tiv.com/fix-cant-close-tabs-samsung-note-4-tabs-wont-close-solved/amp/)

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but none of what you have told me has worked. I should make clear this is a tablet, not a phone.

Comment: Oh yeah.. sorry.. my bad. See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89468/cant-switch-close-tabs-in-the-chrome-browser-on-my-android-tablet and also try updating/downgrading (sometimes there are bugs in new updates) the app.. Tell me when you've read this, I'll delete the answer.