# Can't close browser tabs

Tags: chrome-for-android, firefox-for-android, browser-tabs

I'm having an issue with an LG G pad.

Chrome 87.0.4280.101

Firefox Daylight 84.1.2 (Build #2015783145)

OS Android 5.1.1 LG-V940n Build/LMY47V

I don't do much with it other than email, browsing and Netflix. Everything was working fine until last month, then it decided that I can't close browser tabs anymore. I'm assuming there was an update that happened.

I have found three other posts on this (see below) sorry for the duplicate.

[I can't open or close any tabs on my Android tablet in Chrome](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232023/i-cant-open-or-close-any-tabs-on-my-android-tablet-in-chrome)

[I'm unable to toggle between Chrome Tabs](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/231895/im-unable-to-toggle-between-chrome-tabs)

[Can't switch/close tabs in the Chrome browser on my Android tablet](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89468/cant-switch-close-tabs-in-the-chrome-browser-on-my-android-tablet)

This happens with Chrome and has happened with Firefox too. Both and seems to be related to video. Once I view video in a new tab, I can't switch, close or create tabs. However, I can open links in new tabs, but I cannot switch to them. I can switch to/from private mode as well, but still can't do anything with tabs.

Additionally, I have tried simplified mode and desktop with no difference.

If I rotate the tablet it seems to unlock the tabs and I can switch/open/close them again.

In the posts above, mention going to settings->developer options which I don't have. And why should a simple user of chrome need to tweak any developer options.

Do I have any options than rotating the thing and waiting for an update that hopefully fixes the issue?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Does it happen when videos are playing in full and normal screen?

Comment: If you have read about Developer Options menu I am sure you have also card that it is hidden by default and needs to be activated by tapping the build number a few times? Every regular Android phone has that menu.

Comment: Good catch. It seems to happen after I go to full screen on the video (Youtube in this case). I tapped on the build a bunch of time and it said I'm now a developer, but I don't have any other options in Chrome.

Comment: The Developer Options menu is shown in the Android Settings app, not in Chrome.

Comment: Yup, I found the dev ops in Android.